# Dropping a conditional slider input after the user input from selectInput has been changed in a shiny application

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I have two datasets with different time lengths. I would like the user to be able to select the range of years to view based on the dataset that they select. Currently, I am using two conditional statements. The problem with what I have done so far is that once the user changes the input/dataset they want to look at, both slider inputs are present.

```
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("data", "Select what you would like to see", 
                    c("Option 1", "Option 2", Option 3")
                    )

conditionalPanel(
           condition = ("input.data == 'Option 1' || 'Option 2')
           sliderInput(
                       "range", "Range of years:", min = ####, 
                        max = year(Sys.Date()), value = c(1990,                   
                        year(Sys.Date()))
                      ),

conditionalPanel(
           condition = ("input.data == 'Option 3')
           sliderInput(
                       "range", "Range of years:", min = ####, 
                        max = year(Sys.Date()), value = c(1985,                   
                        year(Sys.Date())
```

Is there a way to drop one of the slider inputs after the user input has been made? I have tried using conditional statements (for & while), but I am hoping that there is an easier way.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up utilyzing renderUI, which acts on the server side. code looks like this:

```
output$ui <- renderUI({
   if(is.null(input$data))
      return()
   switch(input$data, "Option 1" = sliderInput("range", "Range of years:",
          min=1990, max = year(Sys.Date()))
          ,
          input$data, "Option 2" = sliderInput("range", "Range of years:",
          min=1990, max = year(Sys.Date()))
          ,
          input$data, "Option 3" = sliderInput("range", "Range of years:",
          min=1985, max = year(Sys.Date()))
})
```

There is probably a more efficient and elegant way of doing this, but this worked for me. 
[Here is a link for additional dynamic user interface information.](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)